# ReactJS: Appending new object to an existing array with spread

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, spread-syntax

I have this array object to begin with

```
[
  {
    "name": "child",
    "pax": {}
  }
]
```

I wish to append new property which is an array. then I want to update/insert new object into that array. But something is wrong with my code

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([
    {
      name: "child",
      pax: {}
    }
  ]);

  function appendage({ id, age }) {
    const toSaveArr = arr.map(o => {
      if (o.name === "child") {
        return {
          ...o,
          age: o.age
            ? o.age.map(o2 => {
                if (o2.id === id) {
                  return {
                    id: o2.id,
                    age
                  };
                }
                console.log("o2", o2);
                //something is wrong here
                //why is it not adding new object?
                return [
                  ...o2,
                  {
                    id,
                    age
                  }
                ];
              })
            : [{ id, age }]
        };
      }
      return o;
    });

    setArr(toSaveArr);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setNum(num + 1);

          appendage({
            id: num + 1,
            age: num + 1
          });
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button>update age where id equal to 2</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mclean-107q2

I think I've used spread operator wrongly here.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg if no object then append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we check to see if there is already an age object, if yes, we add a new object using spread operator; if no, we insert the object;

relevant **code**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([
    {
      name: "child",
      pax: {}
    }
  ]);

  function appendage({ id, age }) {
    console.log("inside appendage with ", id, " and age:", age);
    const toSaveArr = arr.map(o => {
      if (o.name === "child") {
        if (o.age) {
          console.log("age exists");
          o.age = [
            ...o.age,
            {
              id: id,
              age: age
            }
          ];
          console.log("O", o);
        } else {
          o.age = [
            {
              id: id,
              age: age
            }
          ];
          console.log("O", o);
        }
        /*return {
          ...o,
          age: o.age
            ? o.age.map(o2 => {
                if (o2.id === id) {
                  return {
                    id: o2.id,
                    age
                  };
                }
                console.log("o2", o2);
                //something is wrong here
                //why is it not adding new object?
                return [
                  ...o2,
                  {
                    id,
                    age
                  }
                ];
              })
            : [{ id, age }]
        };
      */
      }
      return o;
    });

    setArr(toSaveArr);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setNum(num + 1);

          appendage({
            id: num + 1,
            age: num + 1
          });
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button>update age where id equal to 2</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

working [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/owhcq)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function you pass into `map` returns an array, but that is not how `map` works. You can only change existing objects in the array, but not add new ones. What you can do is use for example [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the object in the array and check if the result is `undefined`.

```js
const result = o.age.find(o2 => o2.id === id);
if (result) {
    result.age = age;
} else {
    o.age.push({ id: o2.id, age: age });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use find method in your array to find specific value which is here `"child"`:

```
import React, { useState, useDebugValue } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([
    {
      name: "child",
      pax: []
    }
  ]);

  function appendage({ id, age }) {
    var newarr = arr;
    var add = {
      id: id,
      age: age
    };
    newarr.find(el => el.name === "child").pax = [
      ...newarr.find(el => el.name === "child").pax,
      add
    ];

    setArr(newarr);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{num}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setNum(num + 1);

          appendage({
            id: num + 1,
            age: num + 1
          });
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      <button>update age where id equal to 2</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: why you change my pax from object to array?

Comment: @Hanz where are you trying to add your new object?